# Trouble compiling code from LLVM Kaleidoscope tutorial

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm

When I used `g++ -std=c++17 toy.cpp -o toy` to compile the toy.cpp file without the header `#include "llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h"` in the toy.cpp file, everything was fine and I produced a "working" binary file.

However, when I added the `#include "llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h"` line to the toy.cpp file and compile it with the command `g++ -std=c++17 toy.cpp -o toy`, the terminal crushed me with the following output:

```
-bash: llvm-config: command not found
toy.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h' file not found
#include "llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h"
```

The same thing still happens even if I used
"clang++ -g -O3 toy.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core` -o toy"
instead of "clang++ -g -O3 toy.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflag`" in the tutorial. My guess is that there's something wrong with the llvm-config thing. It's been bothering me for a while, please teach me how to solve it.

[Link to the toy.cpp code](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl02.html)

Comment: So, you need to install llvm-config. Have you done that?

Comment: I used `brew install llvm` in the terminal before compiling it (and it runs successfully), does llvm-config come with that command?

Comment: Try to run the command "llvm-config --cxxflag" to see if it points to the right include folder. If not, try to find it (for linux) "find /usr -name STLExtras.h | grep "llvm/ADT" "

Comment: I just give the command a try and it returns `-I/usr/local/Cellar/llvm@8/8.0.1_3/include -std=c++11   -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS`. What is this mess? And what should I do with it?

Comment: I just used `g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -c $(llvm-config --cxxflags) toy.cpp -o toy.o` to compile the file and it gives me errors stating that make::unique should be llvm::unique (but the good thing is that it can find STLExtras now), why does this happen?

Comment: After I changed the make::unique to llvm::unique, I produced a broken toy.o file which cannot be executed even after I used the `chmod +x` command. Jeez, this is hard.

Comment: You cannot execute object files. You have to link them into an executable. Did you mean to put `-c`?

Comment: And, yes, programming is hard :)

Comment: I used `./toy` and it works, so far. Thanks :D

Comment: You need the version of `llvm-config` that fits to the `llvm-project` repo version you took the `kaleidoscope` tutorial from. I just compiled it and posted the taken path [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127083/how-to-compile-llvm-kaleidoscope-tutorial/66722436#66722436).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is "llvm-config" is not working as expected.

Just check with `which llvm-config` to figure out whether you got this program. (mine is `/usr/local/opt/llvm@8/bin/llvm-config`). Or you can install with `brew install llvm`.

By the way, I came up with the same issue lately on kaleidoscope tutorial (ch2), but I want to know why the `#include "llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h` fails after several attempts on `$(llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags)`, etc or we aren't able to compile following chapter's code simply by removing the header declaration when llvm include files are necessary.